# Calculating variance of poisson distributed random variable

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, arithmetic

I am calculating variance of a Poisson distributed random variable with mean $\lambda$. I am doing it in the following way:

$\mathbb{V}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \lambda^2 \\
= \sum_{x\geq 0} \quad x^2\frac{e^{-\lambda} \quad\lambda^x}{x!} - \lambda^2\\
= 0 + \lambda e^{-\lambda} + \sum_{x\geq 2} \quad x^2\frac{e^{-\lambda} \quad\lambda^x}{x!}-\lambda^2\\
= \lambda e^{-\lambda} + e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2\sum_{x\geq 2} \quad \frac{\lambda^{x-2}}{(x-2)!}\\
=\lambda e^{-\lambda} + \lambda^2 -\lambda^2\\
=\lambda e^{-\lambda}$

The answer is wrong. But I cannot understand what am I doing wrong in breaking the summation on line 3.

Edit: shown step 4 to answer a comment

Comment: How do you get that sum over $x \geq 2$ to be equal to $\lambda^2$?

Comment: I have added a step.

Comment: Going from line 3 to line 4, you've assumed $x^2/x! = 1/(x - 2)!$ for $x \geq 2$, which is not true. Also, your $-\lambda^2$ term disappears on line 4 and then reappears on line 5.

Comment: Often times it's easier to start by finding $E[X(X-1)]$.  Also, please add the self-study tag, and I'll assist further.

Comment: @Alex I totally missed that! The $\lambda^2$ is a typo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson distribution is one of those distributions that involves a factorial denominator.  This this type of distribution, the simplest way to find the raw and central moments is to first find the expected values of the [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials):

$$\mathbb{E}((X)_r) = \mathbb{E} \bigg( X(X-1) \cdots (X-r+1) \bigg) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty x(x-1) \cdots (x-r+1) \cdot \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} e^{-\lambda}.$$

Have a go at solving this infinite sum (it is relatively simple) and then you will have a general form for the expected value of the falling factorials of $X$.  These are all polynomials in $X$, so they can be used to find any of the raw moments or central moments by appropriate arithmetic.  In your particular case you want the variance, so you will want to look at the expected values of the falling factorials up to $r=2$.